# node.js: Is it safe to use userinput as commandline arguments?

Tags: node.js, shell, express, security, command-line

I'd like to use child_process.execFile(file[, args][, options][, callback]) (node.js) to call a specific application on the host server. The "file"argument is defined by me. Is it safe to pass unsanitized userinput to 'args' argument? If no: How can I sanitize the input?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is definitely not safe at all. A user can intelligently end the command and perform a separate command, and depending on the permission level your node app is running, would be able to do a ton of things.

I am uncertain how you are retrieving user input, but, you should parse the input for specific arguments. For example, say your wanted to pass in `arg`, you should take that from the user input and pass along `child_process.execFile(file, arg, ...)`.

You should probably also sanitize the user input, which can be done various ways, including using the [sanitize library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize). By parameter-izing the input, it would be rather straightforward to sanitize while also limiting what can be passed in.

===========================================================================

Update:

In theory, if you need to be able to allow the user to pass anything, you could start the action in some closed off environment, like maybe a container, though that is rather complicated and, depending on how much a person wants to muck with your system, has a pretty high chance of being pwned.

Comment: _"A user can intelligently end the command and perform a separate command"_. How would that specifically apply to `child_process.execFile()`, since that doesn't use a shell?

Comment: I guess my answer may be purely theoretical at this point, but based on experience, the way I see it is that if there's a will, then there's a way. Your best bet would be to make sure that the child process runs in an environment that can't mess up things in your overall system.

Comment: If you just try hard enough you can hack anything. What I want to know is: Is the function designed to pass 'args' are always as arguments and not as a new command? (Of coures if there are no Bugs in the function)